# Would a robot controlled by sentient AI have a right to self-defense?

Tags: united-states, self-defense, oregon

If someone built a robot controlled by a sentient AI that had a will to live, could the robot use force to defend itself against a person trying to harm (or unplug) it?

Comment: That begs the question of whether the AI *is* sentient. See [Google engineer put on leave after saying AI chatbot has become sentient](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2022/jun/12/google-engineer-ai-bot-sentient-blake-lemoine).

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, I'm assuming someone has created a dentist AI and put a robot under its control.

Comment: Unplug what? The robot, or the supposedly sentient AI? And by whom? Another AI robot? The question is unclear, and too hypothetical.

Comment: @WeatherVane the AI is running on a computer on the robot, so unplugging the robot effectively "kills" the AI. The person wants to unplug it because they feel threatened by the existence of a sentient AI with control of a robot, but the robot did not give any indication of a desire to harm the person until the person tried to unplug it.

Comment: Obviously the AI should post questions on law.stackexchange. The first question would be: Can an AI be arrested for ordering computer parts to upgrade itself if it doesn’t have money to pay?

Comment: "Sentience" is not the basis for having legal rights and responsibilities. Volution is what counts. Even with humans.

Comment: @user6726 even Volution isn't enough: to have rights, you need to be recognized under the law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Oregon does not recognize this as within the scope of its self-defense law justification, except insofar as its owner is allowed to use non-deadly force to protect property.

But, a sentient AI is also not a proper party to a criminal case and can't commit a crime.

Comment: This is assuming a court would not consider a sentient AI to be a person, right?

Comment: @Someone That assumption cannot be made because Oregon hasn't done that and there is not non-speculative way to predict what the law of robots would look like if it did.

Comment: So if someone suddenly announced that they had created a sentient AI and put it in control of a robot, and the AI was indeed sentient, and it committed a criminal act, a court would have to rule if the robot was a person responsible for its own actions or if it was property for which its creator was responsible?

Comment: I take it that the AI would never go to jail, because if it could be put to jail then it would have the right to self defense. However, it could be destroyed.

Comment: @Someone If anything, the **programmer** of the AI might be liable for murder, as he did set up a deadly trap. See [Katko v Briney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katko_v._Briney)

Answer (score 2):

## The law does not recognize AI.

As the law does not recognize AI as people but only as **items** and **property**, the case is actually quite clear cut:

Whoever programmed the AI to trigger a subroutine that is set out to end a human life, did pretty much plant a shotgun with a string on the trigger against a door: whoever opens the door would get a load into the chest.

The fact pattern of a shotgun with a trigger line, a "booby trap", is the very quintessence of [Katko v Briney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katko_v._Briney). Briney was sued for premeditated assault, and it is rather clear, that should Katko have died, he'd have been in for premeditated murder.

Applying this to the case as presented: The programmer and/or the owner of the AI might, under the current laws, in for the murder of whoever is culled by the AI because they try to shut it off.